# Showing that $(S^1,\cdot)$ is isomorphic to $(SO(2),\cdot)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

Let $$S^1 := \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1\}$$ I know that $$\operatorname{SO}(2) = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos \varphi & -\sin \varphi\\
  \sin\varphi & \cos \varphi
 \end{pmatrix} : \varphi \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$ So to show that $$(S^1,\cdot) \cong (SO(2),\cdot)$$ it would be natural to consider the mapping induced by the polar representation of a complex number $z \in S^1$ $$z = \cos \varphi + i\sin \varphi \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
  \cos \varphi & -\sin \varphi\\
  \sin\varphi & \cos \varphi
 \end{pmatrix}$$ This mapping is clearly surjective. My problem is now, that the maping is not really well defined because of the periodicity of the trigonometric functions. How can I overcome this formally? I thought of using the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: You are on the right track: both objects have the property $M(\theta)\cdot M(\phi) = M(\theta+\phi)$.

Comment: If you have two numbers on the complex unit circle that become the same $SO(2)$-matrix under this map, can they possibly be distinct points on the circle?

Comment: @Arthur No this cannot be.

Comment: Then you have shown that the mapping is injective as well, so it is bijective.

Comment: Well, the argument of a complex number is only well-defined up to integer multiples of $2 \pi$, too.  If you want to be very formal, you could identify $S^1$ with $\mathbb{R}/2\pi \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, your map is $$z\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}\Re z&-\Im z\\\Im z&\Re z\end{pmatrix} $$
and hence well-defined (with inverse 
$$ \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\mapsto a+ic$$
also well-defined)

Comment: I also saw this. So I could restrict this mapping to $S^1$ and I would get the desired isomorphism is that right?

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider the following surjective group homomorphisms:

$f: \mathbb{R}^+ \to S^1 \, ; \, t \mapsto e^{ti}$

$g: \mathbb{R}^+ \to SO(2) \, ; \, t \mapsto \left( \begin{matrix} \cos t & -\sin t \\ \sin t & \cos t \end{matrix} \right)$

Each has kernel $K = \{2 \pi n : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$, so that
$S^1 \cong \mathbb{R}^+ / K \cong SO(2)$.